# Allow redirect after successful login

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess that denies access to all of my documents EXCEPT for the login page, which is `apiLogin.php`. As shown in my code below:

```
<Limit GET POST>
       order deny,allow
       deny from all
       allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
       order deny,allow
       deny from all
</Limit>

DirectoryIndex apiLogin.php

<Files ~ "execute.php$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files ~ "printAPI.php$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>

<Files ~ "Orders.xml$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>

<Files ~ "Config.xml$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)s_orderlist(/|$) - [F]
```

I want my `execute.php` to allow redirection from `apiLogin.php` AFTER a successful login(Which is already being checked by a form - I can't redirect it to the page however because the htaccess denies it / I need an exception). How do I achieve this? Do I do this through .htaccess or through php?

Comment: Ask one question at a time please, unless they are very closely related (which these two don't seem to be).

Comment: @ADyson Oh, I thought they were, I'll edit it out of the question

Comment: `I want my execute.php to allow redirection from apiLogin.php AFTER a successful login`...well it's PHP which issues the redirect command. But if you redirect to a page which htaccess doesn't allow the user to visit, then that will be a problem.

Comment: My php already has a form that checks for a successful login, the only thing I need is the permission from htaccess to redirect to execute.php

Comment: I would ask...why you are using htaccess to deny access to those in the first place? I think from previous questions you were maybe trying to build some sort of routing engine . If so then I suggest you study existing examples of the techniques involved, because it's not simple and seem to be trying to piece it together bit by bit, without really understanding where you're going, or fully understanding the technologies you're trying to use to do it.

Comment: If you're trying to route everything through index.php (so you can have extensionless URLs, and URLs which don't directly equate to a file, such as you'd have in an MVC style application), then you shouldn't be trying to redirect to a specific PHP script anyway...you should be redirecting to a route URL which your main PHP script would then process and use the information in it to decide which PHP functions to execute in order to provide the correct response.

Comment: But I don't know for sure if that's what you're trying to achieve, it all seems a bit jumbled tbh.

Comment: I've been asked to try this method and usually don't ask anything unless I really can't solve the problem myself. I wish I could educate myself in this because I find it interesting and intriguing, but sadly I'm bound to a deadline which leaves little time

Comment: And I'm denying access to protect the files, so it can't be reached from a direct URL - so to improvise something I thought it seemed logical to make an exception to allow access

Comment: `so it can't be reached from a direct URL` if it can't be reached then it can't be reached. Htaccess is a static file, it can't make exceptions or be changed in mid-request. What would the exception be based on exactly anyway? If you actually just want to deny access to users who aren't logged in, then the PHP scripts themselves need to check the login status of the user (which is usually stored in the session) before continuing to do any more processing. Denying via htaccess is an outright ban - Apache will deny the user access before any PHP is even executed.

Comment: @ADyson `If you actually just want to deny access to users who aren't logged in` - This is exactly what I want. The one that gave me this task told me that htaccess would be enough to deny access to other users so I assumed that like a lot of things you'd have an exception that could grant you access under certain circumstances or meeting criteria. I'll check with the login session instead to fix this issue and only let the .htaccess allow users that use our IP address. Thanks for everything.

Comment: `The one that gave me this task told me that htaccess would be enough to deny access to other users`...well they were sadly mistaken. I mean, they're right in the sense that it denies access, but wrong in the assumption that it can be flexible about who the request is coming from. Perhaps they misunderstood your intention. (Or if it was them who gave you the intention, then they simply don't understand the technology properly.)

Comment: Bear in mind you also have some XML files in there. PHP cannot control access to those directly. If they shouldn't be public, then they should not be in a folder which can be served by Apache, instead they should be in another folder outside the website root. If you need to show the contents to the user, then you need a PHP script which can retrieve the data from those files and show it to the user (having first checked their login status).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow `execute.php` in ht access and add a session check.

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] != true){
       echo 'not logged in';
       header("Location: apiLogin.php");
       exit;
    }
```

And on apiLogin, when user login set session to true

`$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer based on the comments ! :) I had it figured out by then, but I still appreciate it